# Inline hash assignment and usage

Tags: ruby

I have the following method declaration:

```
  def do_staff
    param_a = condition1 && condition2
    param_b = 100
    param_c = param_a ? 'good' : 'bad'
    # method logic implementation ....
  end
```

After using `rubocop gem` to analyze my code, I found that `do_staff` has more than 10 lines of code, so I need to add the params definition to single hash such as:

```
args = { param_a: condition1 && condition2, param_b: 100, param_c: args[:param_a] ? 'good' : 'bad' }
```

The `args` declaration will definitely throw `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` because of `param_c`:

```
{ param_c: args[:param_a] ? 'good' : 'bad' }
```

**The Question is:**

Is there any possibility in Ruby to implement such inline declaration where I can avoid repeating the logic of `param_a` definition while defining `param_c`?

Comment: Did you consider moving the complex condition into a method on its own? Btw. Rubocop is not only complaining about the number of lines, if you just write it in one line it will complain about the line length or the complexity.

Comment: @spickermann sure, currently I moved it to different method, I'm just checking if there is some way to define & use the hash at same time.

Comment: @spickermann, I don't have issue with line length, I updated my question, what I'm trying to mention that is to get value of `param_a`, I need to do some db calls, which I need to avoid repeating while defining `param_c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a line like this

```
variable = { a: 1, b: variable[:a] }
```

then the right side of the assignment is evaluated first - that means the hash is defined first. Then in a second step, the defined hash is assigned to the variable on the left. Therefore the `variable[:a]` reference in the hash definition must fail, because the hash hasn't been assigned to the `variable` at that point in time.

In your example, I would extract the condition for `params_a` into a method on its own and - if the evaluation is expensive - memorize its result:

```
def do_staff
  {
    param_a: a_condition,
    param_b: 100,
    param_c: (a_condition ? 'good' : 'bad')
  }
end

private

def a_condition
  # note we cannot use `||=` here because the result 
  # of the condition might be `nil` or `false`
  @a_condition = condition1 && condition2 unless defined?(@a_condition)
end
```

Or you could do the evaluation in the `do_staff` method once:

```
def do_staff
  a_condition = condition1 && condition2

  {
    param_a: a_condition,
    param_b: 100,
    param_c: (a_condition ? 'good' : 'bad')
  }
end
```

Furthermore, I would suggest moving the `a_condition ? 'good' : 'bad'` part into a method on its own too - just to increase readability. But that refactoring depends on your dependencies and might not make much sense in the context of the sample code in your question.